# is "merablum" or "merablem" a word?

Tags: etymology, idioms, is-it-a-word, subcontinental-english

is there a word "merablum"? maybe "merablem"? It means scrap or remnant of food left on a plate. I always thought it was a word but I googled it and - nothing. Is Google unaware of it or is it a made up word? Grandpa and Grandma Turner always used it. Grandpa did sometimes use Hindi words, it's true, but this I thought was English. The merablums are the best bits. Like the crunchy bits. Help.

Comment: Welcome, sorry I cannot help, and +1 for a query about a word apparently specific to your family. Many families have their own unique bits of vocabulary, and I find such fascinating. I'd create a fresh tag for this if I knew the appropriate term: *genolect* seemed a likely candidate but is not in OED. Please do get back to us with in-family research on where this one might have come from.

Comment: You might wanna do some research on it, now that you have raised a question and we're all curious. It may be common to your place or area. If you could provide more detail regarding the background, we may give you a satisfactory answer. +1

Comment: If the remains are dry, then they're called 'crumbs'. If not dry, then maybe 'dregs' (but that's more for what's at the bottom of a barrel than a plate.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any such word with either of those spellings, and I also looked for words with the "mira-" prefix.  In addition, I used the [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=%2a&loc=revfp2&clue=food) and [Wordsmyth](http://www.wordsmyth.net/) reverse dictionaries to find all the words with "food" in their definitions, and I didn't see anything close to merablum/merablem.  Also, I tried using [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) to translate various English phrases such as "scrap of food", "remnant of food", "crunchy bits" into Hindi, and didn't find anything in Hindi that sounds close to "merablum" (Google Translate showed the phonetic spelling of the Hindi translations).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, all. I shall try to answer succinctly. My father used this term, and so did all our family. My father lived in India, specifically Ballygunge, near what was called Calcutta, from 1917 to 1921 or 1922. He brought several Hindi words and phrases to Australia when he started our family here. I never thought of this word as one of his Hindi words. I am now asking siblings for their memories of derivation of the word, but the consensus is that it was just a word we always used, and it is only recently that I began to wonder about it, when my husband told me he didn't know what it meant, and questioned it. That is the background.
2/7/14:
I will edit my original post rather than create a new one. The consensus seems to be that this word is unique family jargon. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it's something to do with the Latin word *mirabilium* ("of wonders", "of miracles")?  The expression "miriabile dictu" ("it's a miracle") is fairly common, so perhaps this could originate as part of a similar expression.  Google doesn't return anything obvious, though...

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I am seeing "merablum" or "merablem." Googling it only results in your question topping the list of results. There are no other trustworthy citations or mentions. So, maybe it is just jargon that hasn't found its way to dictionaries.

The words meaning food leftovers are orts (ort), remnants or just leftovers.